# Using data returned by Firebase Realtime Database in TypeScript - Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for now and I'm having problems to use the returned data of database in TypeScript.

When I do this code, I can use the results in HTML without problem:

TypeScript:

```
clientsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
clients: Observable<Client[]>;

constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.clientsRef = db.list('clients');
    this.clients = this.clientsRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes =>
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    );
  }
```

HTML:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let client of clients | async" (click)="update(client)">
      {{client.name}}
</ion-item>
```

This operations are working fine to me. My problem comes when I want to use the variable this.clients in TypeScript code. I can't access the data, like the name, for example, in the same way I use in HTML.

When I print in console the variable the result is:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

I don't know how to show the real data returned using TypeScript. Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not acquainted with snapshotChanges and pipe(),

```
    this.list.on('value', itemSnapshot=> {
            this.data = [];
            console.log('************',itemSnapshot);
            itemSnapshot.forEach( itemSnap => {
                  console.log(itemSnap.val());
                  this.data[itemSnap.key] = itemSnap.val();
            });
    })
```

The important thing to note is the .val()

In your case, if 'clients' has childs say name, company and so on,
you can use:

```
itemSnap.val().name
itemSnap.val().company
```

to extract the specifc values like you need.
Hope it helps!